# Can SQL before insert triggers access the values of an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I trying to figure out how to write a before insert trigger to prevent someone from adding a user to  ftable if one of the values matches a value

```
INSERT INTO ftable (fname,lname)
VALUES ('Sally','Barnes')
```

How can I access the 'Sally' variable in my before insert trigger to test it? Is it even possible?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You can use `NEW.fname`